# Issue in reading JSON data

Tags: json

I have a PL/SQL code that read the JSON data. The below JSON works fine without any issues.

```
{ "P_REQ_LINE_TBL_ITEM":[ { "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0001", "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year 4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" }, { "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0002", "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year 4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" } ] } )

SET SERVEROUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED LINESIZE 1000 DECLARE -- l_clob CLOB;
   l_top_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
   
   l_req_lines_arr JSON_ARRAY_T; l_req_lines_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
   
   BEGIN
   
   l_top_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T(' { "P_REQ_LINE_TBL_ITEM":[ {
   "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0001",
   "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year
   4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" }, {
   "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0002",
   "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year
   4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" } ] } ');
   l_req_lines_arr := l_top_obj.get_array('P_REQ_LINE_TBL_ITEM');
   
   FOR j IN 0 .. l_req_lines_arr.get_size - 1 LOOP   l_req_lines_obj :=
   TREAT(l_req_lines_arr.get(j) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  --');   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' 
   REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1 : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1'));  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  AMS_LINE_NUM : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('AMS_LINE_NUM'));   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('
   ITEM_DESCRIPTION : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('ITEM_DESCRIPTION'));  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  UNIT_OF_MEASURE : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('UNIT_OF_MEASURE'));  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  UNIT_PRICE : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('UNIT_PRICE'));   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' 
   QUANTITY : ' || l_req_lines_obj.get_string('QUANTITY'));  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  BASE_UNIT_PRICE : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('BASE_UNIT_PRICE'));  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  LINE_TYPE : ' ||
   l_req_lines_obj.get_string('LINE_TYPE')); END LOOP; END;
```

but when I change (added another tag/object P_REQ_LINE_TBL), I get the following error: ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed. Below is the actual json I need to process:

{ "P_REQ_LINE_TBL": { "P_REQ_LINE_TBL_ITEM":[ { "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0001", "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year 4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" }, { "REQ_NUMBER_SEGMENT1": "RQ2223003602", "AMS_LINE_NUM": "0002", "ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "0001 This is a request to exercise Option Year 4.", "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "USD", "UNIT_PRICE": "1", "QUANTITY": "60", "BASE_UNIT_PRICE": "1", "LINE_TYPE": "GOODS" } ] } } )

Please help to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Always tag your SQL questions with `sql` and the particular DBMS (`oracle`) you are using. That will ensure they get the maximum audience